# How to make a dynamic option tag from the values from the columns of the database

Tags: c#, html

this is my code for my aspx.cs file. help me to create a dynamic option tag using the values in the column from the database. 
thanks

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string query = "select * from vehicle where VehicleYear = 2010;
        MSConnector connector = new MSConnector();
        connector.ConnectionString = "SERVER=server;UID=user;Password=password;DATABASE=data;";
        DataSet Make = connector.ExecuteQuery(query);
        DataTable dt = Make.Tables[0];
        data.DataSource = dt;
        data.DataBind();
    }
```

this is my code in my html. instead of typing the  tag one by one. i need to have a dynamic  tag because if the database will be updated the  tag must update too. i really need your help. thanks

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container form-group">
<div class="row">
<form runat="server">
  <div class="col-md-6"><select class="form-control" name="Make" id="make"     runat="server"> 
    <option value="select" selected>Select Make</option>
    <option value="ALFA ROMEO">ALFA ROMEO</option>
    <option value="AUDI">AUDI</option>
    <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
    <option value="DAIHATSU">DAIHATSU</option>
    <option value="FORD">FORD</option>
    <option value="HONDA">HONDA</option>
  </select></div>
```

Comment: You are going to clarify what you mean by "dynamic tag".

Comment: @RonBeyer sir i just edited my codes above. and i just explained above what dynamic is. thanks. by the way sir its not "dynamic tag". it should be "dynamic <option> tag" sorry wrong type

Answer (score 0):

You can check that your data table is empty or not by doing:

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
//by column index you can access the value like
dt.Rows[2].ToString();
//by column name you can access value like
dt.Columns["abc"].ToString();
}
```

By accessing the value(s) from data table by the above mentioned method you can create dynamic tags.

Note: Where '2' is the column index and 'abc' is the column name, You can change as per your table design.

After your Edit:

```
for(int i=0; i<dt.Rows.Count ; i++)
    {
     ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem(dt.Columns["abc"].ToString(),                                           dt.Columns["abc"].ToString();));
     }
```

Make a dropdown in the design page and update list from the code like above mentioned.

Comment: sir how can i get the data from its specific column and row and put it in an option tag in html? thank you @waleedansari

Comment: you can use this code "dt.Columns["abc"].ToString();" and change "abc" with your column name. Kindly check my edits.

Comment: what is ddl sir?  @waleedansari

Comment: ddl is dropdown asp control. add in your design page a dropdown like:
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server">
    </asp:DropDownList> instead of your  div.